# how can I call firebird gen_id

Tags: asp.net, firebird

I can't get the `GEN_ID` function to work.

**Query**

`INSERT INTO "CUSTOMER" (ID, KODU) values(GEN_ID(ID_GEN,1)," + KODU.Text + ");`

**Error**

> Error:Dynamic SQL Error
>   SQL error code = -104
>   Token unknown - line 1

Comment: You actually do have the generator (aka sequence) named "ID_GEN", right?

Comment: `" + KODU.Text + "` looks suspicious. Could you show the real code, because the double quotes around `CUSTOMER` suggest this is the literal query, while this part suggests it isn't (and if it isn't: you are vulnerable to SQL injection).

Comment: Just to be sure I have just tested it and the way you call `gen_id` is correct, so the problem is with something else. The full error message also includes a column and the problematic token; you might want to update your question to include more information (like the full error, and the actual code you use to execute this).

Comment: insert into formula(id,kodu)values(gen_id(formula_id_gen,1)," + kodu.Text + ");

Comment: Please update the question, don't use comments for pertinent information, and what you have in the comment isn't full code: for one where is the opening and closing quote of the text, what is the value of `kodu.Text`; if this is text, then you need to enclose this in single quotes (but seriously: you should use parameters instead of string concatenation). You might also want to remove the semi-colon, it is not actually part of the SQL syntax of Firebird (and I keep forgetting if the Firebird .NET provider strips it out or not).